# Is there a way to add a keybinding shortcut that doesn't conflict with the existing ones (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a keyword shortcut that will close all the editors on the right side from the selected one. Somehow this is not by default in vscode on mac (or maybe just to me), I remember using it on window.

Anyway I created the shortcut based on `cmd+w` closing the selected editor. I thought using `cmd + ->(right arrow) w`. And it works perfectly for closing the editors. But it conflicts with the existing one `cmd + ->` that is used to go to the end of the line. How to make both to work.

I don't want to use other keybindings such as a unique one because these keys combination make sense to me. Well I tried also something like `cmd+r w`. Same problem, there is already a shortcut for `cmd+r`. And can't use it because it  waits for the next key to be added.

Comment: you can't have 2 keybindings that do different things when the editor has the focus (same `when` clause) you must add an additional modifier (Alt/Shift/Ctrl/Cmd) to the first key combo `Shift+Cmd+ArrowRight W` or find another prefix key combo that is not yet used with a `W`

Comment: In general, there is no guarantee that the same keybinding will work on different platforms. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133094

Comment: @rioV8 I was wondering if `cmd+w` can be expanded in this case `cmd+w rightArrow`. I understand they have the same prefix, but they're not the same right? So when trying to use `cmd+w` it says `cmd+w` was pressed. Waiting for the second key of chord... This mean you can't use only `cmd+w` as long as `cmd+w rightArrow` exits.

Comment: yes, if `cmd+w` is bound to some command you can't use it as a prefix without blocking the use of `cmd+w`, `cmd+w` has now turned into a prefix and wants a second key combo

Answer (score 0):

There is already a command that does what you want (that is unound by default).  Put this into your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+right w",                  // choose your keybinding
  "command": "workbench.action.closeEditorsToTheRight"
}
```

That's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> and then a <kbd>w</kbd> (or whatever the <kbd>Alt</kbd> is on a mac.  My guess is that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> is not bound to anything on a mac.

Since there is no `when` clause to distinguish this command from <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>rightArrow</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, using a unique keybinding like `alt+right w` (`option+right w`) is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: Actually `Alt+rightArrow` it's being used for a purpose already. You use `Alt+rightArrow` to go to the end of the first word met from the typing cursor position. Anyway I was looking for a solution that allow using `cmd+w` and `cmd+rightArrow w` because they're not the same, well they start with the same keys but that's different. And not to find unique keys combinations that can be used. No way to remember using just random keys. It's like can we expand existing shortcuts?

Comment: Then what about `Alt+R`?